# How to get the network you're currently on in apeworx?

Tags: ape

In apeworx, I can run:

```
ape run scripts/deploy_contract.py --network rinkeby
```

How do I know that I'm on the `rinkeby` chain in my python `deploy_contract.py` script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to check the [network active provider](https://docs.apeworx.io/ape/stable/methoddocs/managers.html#module-ape.managers.networks) by using the networks local variable.

This will print the current chain id that you're on

```py
def main():
  print(networks.active_provider.chain_id)
```